# Google turns up with bold font in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, font-faces

After I played some ol' skool games like Age of Empires I, Google turned up with bold font in Firefox (any version).
I'm running Windows 7 x64, and application restart or system reboot isn't helping.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Does this help? http://superuser.com/questions/297728/weird-font-in-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is often caused by hardware acceleration, which causes the application to render some fonts in **bold**. It can also be the result of compatibility problems with the current operating system.

I found two possible solutions:

- Enable Windows compatibility mode for Firefox;
- Disable hardware acceleration in Firefox.

Both possible solutions are described [here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/repair-the-google-and-gmail-bold-font-issue/).

Disabling hardware acceleration solved my problem.

Comment: Just a comment to other readers: make sure to re-enable hardware acceleration if this does not fix your issue. Hardware acceleration can dramatically improve the rendering speeds of few sites.